# Generate img tags with Noir from a list

Tags: clojure, noir

I have a list of photo links and would like to generate img tags with clojure and noir.

Here I get the links:

```
(def photos
(->> (get-in result ["photoset" "photo"]) (map #(str "http://farm"(get % "farm")
".staticflickr.com/"(get % "server")"/"(get % "id")"_"(get % "secret")"_b.jpg"))))
```

Result:

```
(http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8087/8455893107_1a3236df06_b.jpg http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8235/8469482476_4c1bf59214_b.jpg)
```

And then I try to generate img tags from that list:

```
(defpage "/" []
 (mylayout/layout
 (doseq [e photos] (prn e))
 ))
```

(calls `(defpartial layout [& content] ...)`

I'm trying to get the following output for each link in  for a noir based site:

```
[:img {:src "url"}]
```

I was trying out this one but without success:

```
(doseq [e photos] ([:img {:src e}]))
```

How can I pass the links to the layout so that it generates img tags?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either of these should work:

```
(map #(vector :img {:src %}) photos)

(for [url photos]
  [:img {:src url}])
```

*Edit*: As [Chuck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50742/chuck) mentioned, `doseq` is for side-effects. You are wanting to "collect" the results and send them to the template. To do this you need to use list comprehension like `for` or just `map` over your collection.

I hate to rain on your parade but just so you know, [noir has been deprecated](http://blog.raynes.me/blog/2012/12/13/moving-away-from-noir/)

Comment: In other words, Blame's mistakes were 1) using `doseq` instead of `for` (`doseq` is for when you don't care about the return value), and 2) putting parens around the vector (you're not trying to call it).